# SQL query for joining data from three tables with reverse relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, relationship

I have three tables: player, games, hide

Here is the Player model

```
  has_many :hides, :foreign_key=> "hider_id",
                   :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :hidees, :through => :hides
```

Here are the attributes belonging to the Hide Model.

```
  attr_accessible :hidee_id

  belongs_to :hider, :class_name => "Player"
  belongs_to :hidee, :class_name => "Game"

  validates :hider_id, :presence => true
  validates :hidee_id, :presence => true
```

Here is the Games model:

```
  has_many :reverse_hides,  :foreign_key => "hidee_id",
                            :class_name => "Hide",
                            :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :hiders, :through => :reverse_hides
```

I want write a query that would return all games that were hidden by the current player.

At present I have: `Game.joins(:hiders)` which returns all games that are marked as hidden, what do i need to do to find the games only hidden by a particular player... for example where('Player.id = ?' hider_id) <-- this did not seem to work.

I appreciate your help and time!

Comment: What does `Game.joins(:hiders).to_sql` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Granted this doesn't take advantage of much Rails magic, but it should work, if I've understood your models properly:

```
Game.joins('JOIN hides ON hides.hidee_id = games.id').where('hides.hider_id = ?', player.id)
```